# OpenCV warpAffine always return 0 matrix

Tags: python, opencv

I am using python opencv version 4.5.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

rigidRect = np.float32([[50,-50],[50,50],[-50,50]])
shiftRect = np.float32([[50,-30],[50,70],[-50,70]])

M = cv2.getAffineTransform(rigidRect, shiftRect) #this return [[1,0,0],[0,1,20]]
validateRect = cv2.warpAffine(rigidRect, M, (2,3))
```

and `validateRect` return a 3 by 2 zeroes matrix.
I thought `validateRect` will equal to `shiftRect`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`warpAffine` is used to transform *an image* using the affine transform matrix. What you are trying to do is to transform *the given points*, which is achieved by the `transform` function. Documentation of [`getAffineTransform`](https://docs.opencv.org/master/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#ga8f6d378f9f8eebb5cb55cd3ae295a999) gives hint about related functions in see also part.

```
validateRect = cv2.transform(rigidRect[None,:,:], M)
```